# Insert into database failed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save the data that I have into mysql database but I am having a hard time in doing it. At first I am success in doing it in my practice data. The problem is that when I add the additional needed informations to my query, my query is not working any more.

The code is this. Just assume that all the variables has its correct corresponding values.

```
<body>

<?php 


$username = "formtemplate";
$password = "admin123";
$hostname = "localhost";
$db = "practice";
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (id_num, emp_name, branch, work_sched, dayoff, transaction, date_from, date_to, time_from, time_to, total, replacement, reason, pending, approve, decline, consume, paid) VALUES ( '$employeeNum', '$name', '$branch', '$workSched', '$dayoff', '$temptable', '$tempdatefrom', '$tempdateto', '$tempTimeFrom', '$tempTimeTo', '$tempTotal', '$tempReplacement', '$tempReason', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no')";

mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql)

or die ( mysql_error() );

echo "success";

?>

</body>
```

here is the database informations

trans_num    int(11)

id_num       varchar(10)

emp_name     varchar(30)

branch       varchar(20)

work_sched   varchar(25)

dayoff       varchar(15)

transaction  varchar(10)

date_from    date

date_to      date

time_from    varchar(25)

time_to      varchar(25)

total        varchar(25)

replacement  varchar(30)

reason       varchar(100)

pending      varchar(5)

approved     varchar(5)

decline      varchar(5)

consume      varchar(5)

paid         varchar(5)

Comment: What is the error returned?

Comment: why `mysql_error()` with `mysqli` extension?

Comment: You should change `mysql_error` to `mysqli_error($dbhandle)` so you aren't mixing mysql and mysqli.

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_*()` with `mysql_*()`. You won't see any error because you're calling the wrong API.

Comment: thank you guys. I haven't realized that I had mixed mysqli and myslq. And also I have found the culprit why I had encountered an error. I was just lacking letter d in the approved column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("username","password","") or die("databse connected");
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("databse not found");

$username=$_post['username'];
$password=$_post['password'];

mysqli`enter code here`_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('$username','$password')");
echo "successfully insert record";


?>
```